# Why does this library dlopen order matter?

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have a library CandData such that (relevant) `$ nm libCandData.so`:

```
             U _ZN10CandHandle13SetCandRecordEP10CandRecord
             U _ZN10CandHandle7SetLockEv
000000011610 T _ZNK10CandRecord13GetCandHeaderEv
             U _ZTI10CandHandle
```

And a library Candidate such that `$ nm libCandidate.so`:

```
00000001f018 T _ZN10CandHandle13SetCandRecordEP10CandRecord
00000001f270 T _ZN10CandHandle7SetLockEv
             U _ZNK10CandRecord13GetCandHeaderEv
000000241500 V _ZTI10CandHandle
```

So, they have circular dependencies. I can load these by lazy loading Candidate first,
in this order with everything working:

```
dlopen("libCandidate.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
dlopen("libCandData.so",  RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

But attempting to lazy-load CandData first:

```
dlopen("libCandData.so",  RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
dlopen("libCandidate.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

causes dlopen to report:

```
dlopen Error: libCandData.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI10CandHandle
```

What I don't understand is why this order matters? By my understanding, `V` means
that the symbol is weakly linked but has a default definition, so can see how that might not be necessary to resolve immediately. But both libraries have a `U->T` dependence in them.

Why does one order work, but not the other?

Comment: IMHO, it is bad practice to have circular dependencies between two shared libraries (you should merge them into a single bigger shared library). And You can link a shared library into another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why this order matters?

The order matters because while unresolved *function* references can be lazily resolved, *data* references can not (and `_ZTI10CandHandle` is not a function).

Instead of looking at the `nm` output, you should look at the relocations (with `readelf -Wr`). You will observe that the relocation type in `libCandidate.so` for symbol `_ZTI10CandHandle` is different from relocation type in `libCandData.so` for symbol `_ZN10CandHandle7SetLockEv`.